# How to use vlookup in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a sheet something like this

```
A B C D
1 2 2
2 3 3
4 5 5
5 7 9
    10 
    11 
    12
```

I would like column D to show values of col A if col B values exist in col C

```
Example:

A B C D
1 2 2 1 
5 7 9 -
```

D would have a value of 1 since Col b val is in Col C and in row 4 Col D would have no value at all

Yes A,B,C,D are labels as per the comments

Comment: You should be able to just use a straight formula without vlookup (although I do love me some vlookup).  Try:  =IF(B1=C1,A1,"") in D1 and fill down column D.

Comment: Is it *'if col B values exist in col C'* or *'if col B equals col C on the same row'*?

Comment: Please review the Excel `VLOOKUP` function as it was designed specifically for your type of problem.  Official documentation: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `vlookup`, `offset` and `iserror` like so:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B2,C:C,1,0)=B2,OFFSET(B2,0,-1)),"-")
```

`offset` used with the -1 parameter will return the cell one column to the left, so you do not need to rearrange the columns in your actual worksheet. `iserror` will check if the lookup failed, and return the specified default value. Finally, you can also specify the exact range to be looked up, in this case as

`VLOOKUP(B2,$C$2:$C$8,1,0)`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `VLOOKUP` here. I think `MATCH` is a better choice.

Try this:

```
D1:D4 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$C$1:$C$7,0)),"",A1)
```

(This assumes that your numerical values start in row 1.)

The output looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+----+---+
|   | A | B | C  | D |
+---+---+---+----+---+
| 1 | 1 | 2 |  2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |  3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |  5 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 7 |  9 |   |
| 5 |   |   | 10 |   |
| 6 |   |   | 11 |   |
| 7 |   |   | 12 |   |
+---+---+---+----+---+
```